# OpenStack-DevStack: Can't successfully run stack.sh

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am having some troubles on running ./stack.sh on my Ubuntu box.
I did download devstack from github, created an account where I will run this,
given this newly created account sudo privileges and finally, created this localrc:

```
HOST_IP=localhost
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
RABBIT_PASSWORD=password
SERVICE_PASSWORD=password
SERVICE_TOKEN=password
```

I ran ./stack.sh and after quite some time, encountered this "keystone" service problem:

```
+ create_keystone_accounts
++ keystone tenant-create --name admin
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store project. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ ADMIN_TENANT=
++ keystone user-create --name admin --pass password --email admin@example.com
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
An unexpected error prevented the server from fulfilling your request. (OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") None None (HTTP 500)
+ ADMIN_USER=
++ keystone role-create --name admin
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store role. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ ADMIN_ROLE=
+ keystone user-role-add --user-id --role-id --tenant-id
usage: keystone user-role-add --user <user> --role <role> [--tenant <tenant>]
keystone user-role-add: error: argument --user/--user-id/--user_id: expected one argument
++ keystone tenant-create --name service
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store project. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ SERVICE_TENANT=
++ keystone role-create --name=Member
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store role. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ MEMBER_ROLE=
++ keystone role-create --name=anotherrole
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store role. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ ANOTHER_ROLE=
++ keystone tenant-create --name=invisible_to_admin
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store project. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ INVIS_TENANT=
++ keystone tenant-create --name=demo
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
Conflict occurred attempting to store project. (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") (HTTP 409)
+ DEMO_TENANT=
++ keystone user-create --name demo --pass password --email demo@example.com
++ grep ' id '
++ get_field 2
++ read data
An unexpected error prevented the server from fulfilling your request. (OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)") None None (HTTP 500)
+ DEMO_USER=
+ keystone user-role-add --user-id --role-id --tenant-id
usage: keystone user-role-add --user <user> --role <role> [--tenant <tenant>]
keystone user-role-add: error: argument --user/--user-id/--user_id: expected one argument
+ keystone user-role-add --user-id --role-id --tenant-id
usage: keystone user-role-add --user <user> --role <role> [--tenant <tenant>]
keystone user-role-add: error: argument --user/--user-id/--user_id: expected one argument
+ keystone user-role-add --user-id --role-id --tenant-id
```

I am quite confused why there are a lot of "Access denied for user 'root@localhost'" errors. As mentioned above, I am running this on another account.
What am I missing here? (e.g. on localrc, other config files?, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you did a mistake in your installation, but please try to use this manual https://gist.github.com/max-lobur/7786074 to install it from scratch. I used it just a few days ago and it works. You can use it with your localrc and also omit 'Install ironic client' step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the ./stack.sh script as a stack user with sudo rights. Check the installation guide at 
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGkZPqhpnSAhVFvI8KHcNKD40QFggkMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.openstack.org%2Fdeveloper%2Fdevstack%2Fguides%2Fsingle-machine.html&usg=AFQjCNGEhxYRot85kfMGm4m48q-INMzAzQ&sig2=nGuBepezVhBm7cpgnnLktA

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Usually is not a good idea to give answer just based on links, because links may expire and then the answer has no useful content. It would be great if you add some of the content in the link to your answer. Furthermore, your link points to a google search. Would you edit your link to the direct address you want to point to?